# Selecting previous 3 ids in mySql offset backwards

Tags: mysql, sql

From a test table with values id `1 to 50` How can I select 3 rows backwards from a given number?

Eg: given number = 20. 3 id's behind = 17.

I'm actually trying to do an offset backwards. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep it simple? like the query below.

```
select 
 *
from 
 test
where 
 id = 5 - 3
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/74afb/3
This way there is no filesort and the index can be used if you made one.

Plus the query optimizer rewrites this query to something like below

```
select 
 test.id as 'id'
from 
 test
where 
 test.id = 2
```

because of the substraction (5 - 3) = 2 is calculated before running the query.

You can see this by running these querys

```
explain extended select * from test where id = 5 - 3;
show warnings;
```

Comment: That's a nice approach too. Why didn't I think of this?

Comment: Because it's not rare to have IDs in a database that are not sequential. Rows get deleted sometimes, you know? Then your query gets the wrong result (or none).

Comment: @fancyPants yes i know MySQL has an DELETE statement... but read what Norman has sad "From a test table with values id 1 to 50 How can I select 3 rows backwards from a given number?" sounds to me this is pretty sequential to me? but indeed when an row/id is missing the approach should be an subquery or an self inner join

Comment: @Norman because it's human nature to make simple things complex..

Answer (score 3):

Order items in descending order and then use standard `LIMIT` with offset:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20, 3
```

You can use it within sub-query to reorder items in ascending order:

```
select * from (select * from TEST order by id desc LIMIT 5, 3) p order by id asc
```

Working [**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0d641/4)

***UPDATE***

Taking only one row (17th in your example, [2nd in my demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0d641/6)):

```
select *
from (select * from TEST order by id desc LIMIT 5, 3) p
order by id asc
limit 1
```

***UPDATE2***

Query which returns the same row no matter how many rows are in the table:

```
select * from
(select * from
 (select * from TEST order by id asc LIMIT 5) p2
 order by id desc LIMIT 4) p
order by id asc
limit 1
```

Comment: I need only the 17. In your example - 2. I've managed what you did before I asked here :-)

Comment: Use the sub-query and add another `LIMIT 1` into outer query.

Comment: In your answer, If I add more numbers, 2 becomes 3...

Comment: @Norman I've added another version.

Comment: it's subquery madness... three full table scans and filesorts are needed when there is no index even with index the query will need to do two full table scans and two filesorts. You should try running this query on an table what contains 1M records or more..